# Pyppeteer code freezes after launching chrome

Tags: python, windows, pyppeteer

This is a web scraper on Python using pyppeteer
Code part:

```
async def process(query):


  print('START PROCESS')


  async with aiofiles.open(os.path.join(BASEDIR, config['PARSER']['Proxies']), mode='r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    proxies = await f.readlines()
    await f.close()

  proxies = [x.strip() for x in proxies if x != '']
  proxy = random.choice(proxies)


  print('TEST')
  browser = await launch(headless=False, args=['--no-sandbox', '--proxy-server='+proxy, ])
  print(4)
  #Some code
```

Async run some chrome processes using pyppeteer. It works perfect on Linux (Debian) but doesn't work at all on Windows. Browsers launches but even print(4) not run. Code freezes after launching browsers and does't trow any errors. What can I do with it?

Comment: Have you tried updating Chrome? Maybe it's the version. Also, which browsers have you tried using on Windows?

Comment: I use chromium that included in pyppeteer. Version is 69. Hmm... I'll try to use Chrome installed on computer (Version 80)

Comment: No, with installed Chrome it dosn't work too

Comment: @Qwentor Have you found some solution for this? I am also getting same error.